# Source of overcounting in delegation formation

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

**Problem:** Three delegates are to be chosen from a group of four lawyers, a priest, and three professors. In how many ways can the delegation be chosen if it must include at least one professor?

I realize there are $C(8,3)$ total ways to form a delegation of three (not satisfying the constraint). The total number of delegations *without* a professor is $C(5,3)$. Thus, the number of delegations with at least one professor is given by $C(8,3)-C(5,3)=56-10=46$.

My question concerns how to go about this in a different way such as $C(3,1)\cdot C(7,2)$, where there will be clear overcounting because there is only one priest, but that representation is as if there were two priests. Now, $C(3,1)\cdot C(7,2)=63$. How could I correct for the extra $17$ delegations introduced? That is, how can I pinpoint exactly where the overcounting is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

All the delegations including more than one professor will be overcounted.  Those with two professors will be counted twice, once with each professor being the one counted in the $C(3,1)$.  Those with three professors will be counted three times for the same reason.  The overcounting has nothing to do with having only one priest.  Your $C(3,1)$ picks a professor, then $C(7,2)$ picks two of the remaining people.

Comment: Is there an easy way to adjust for the overcounting then? Or is my set up somewhat hopelessly flawed?

Comment: @interrogative you could perhaps break into cases based on how many professors were in fact in the delegation making it $\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{5}{0}$ but this is not recommended for larger problems.  Suppose you were making a size 40 delegation with 100 available professors...

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks that makes sense!